# Azure AD B2C: Persisting claim during local account sign-up

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've created a custom extension property called `extension_compName`.
Through local account sign-up this value is entered by the user.
In the `TechnicalProfile` I'd like to persist this value to the field `companyName`of Azure AD. I tried to use the following `PersistedClaims` setting:

```
<PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_compName" PartnerClaimType="companyName" />
```

However, this doesn't work and gives me following error on local account sign-up page:
`Unable to validate the information provided.`
How could I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to add this persisted claim line to the AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail technical profile. This technical profile is called by the Sign Up technical profile as a validation technical profile to try and create the account in the directory.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-user-input?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#include-a-claim-in-the-token

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/azureadb2ccommunity.io/wiki/LocalAccount-Sign-In-and-Sign-Up-policy

You also need to enable your custom policy to use extension attributes.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

`CompanyName` is not available to be written to. See the attributes available here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes

You can simply use the extension attribute

```xml
<PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_compName" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this information. Most of these findings are already clear. Coud you explain why `CompanyName` in AAD is readonly? Doesn't make much sense to me. However, when using MS Graph I can set the `CompanyName` field.